# how to create this type of card with half image outside using css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

how to create this type of card using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure CSS solution for your problem:

You can change the `img` as you like

**Run the code snippet below**

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #75d6e9;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#box p {
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box">
    <p>Fashion</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Fthinking_woman%2Fthinking_woman_PNG11638.png&f=1&nofb=1" alt="">
</div>
```

Hope it gives you an idea of how it is working.

It could be improved by making it responsive, but that is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tags was `bootstrap` so I assumed that you are using it. To get the whole effect I used some bootstrap classes to get the basic `card` and to get the image "outside" a bit just a negative margin.

[image]

**Check the DEMO below.**

```css
.card-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card-body img {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card bg-info rounded">
    <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h3 class="text-white mb-0">Fashion</h3>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can create image containing blue box, woman,text and white background (all as one image)
2. blue box with text positioned by CSS and woman image with transparent background a top of it
3. transparent woman image with another image (blue box and text) as background-image